# what is the best way to pop-up a print feature of may dom-pdf output

Tags: jquery, printing, pdf-generation

Hi I would like to us you Guru's out there if you a more nicer way in printing a pdf

I have generated a nice pdf contents using dompdf it's just all text with one logo.

Then I have a button where when it is click my php script will save the pdf on a my servers folder and then what happens when the user is redirected on the last page.. he / she has a button to print it..

so ? is there an automatic print javascript / jquery function to automatically print the pdf without dipslaying it?

or will it be displayed but being printed right away?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the PDF Viewer component of the Syncfusion which has an option to print the PDF document, you can also use it to display the PDF document in the MVC application. www.syncfusion.com , you can directly try the online sample in the location http://mvc.syncfusion.com/sfreportingmvcsamplebrowser/MVC/10.1.0.44/PdfViewer_MVC/Samples/4.0/GettingStarted/ThroughView

-Suresh

Answer (score 0):

dompdf (0.6 beta) can embed javascript (see example [Script > Javascript](http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/examples.php)) that will print the PDF.
In order to print it without displaying it, you can create an invisible iframe, and put the ID of this iframe in the "target" attribute of the link to the PDF.

```
<iframe style="position: absolute; left: -10000px" id="pdf-iframe" name="pdf"></iframe>

<a href="dompdf.php?foo=bar=baz" target="pdf-iframe">Print PDF!</a>
```

Note that I didn't put `display: none` on the iframe as this make the iframe "unusable" in certain browsers.
I think this is how the Google Docs print system works.